# Good Pair corollary of the excision theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I have problem with understanding the following proof

[image]

$q_*$ is isomorphism as q is a quotient map and so outside A, it is a homeomorphism implies that $q_*$ induces isomorphism.

Given the above theorem and its proof,

I have difficulty in understanding the following concepts:

1) What exactly do you mean by quotient map q: (X,A) $\to$ (X/A, A/A)? If possible please explain by taking a particular example.

2)The last statement " $q_*$ is isomorphism as q is a quotient map and so outside A, it is a homeomorphism implies that $q_*$ induces isomorphism." Please elaborate on this or paste a link where a proof of this statement has been given.

The above proof has been taken from the book Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher.

Comment: At a minimum I think you should cite the book (or paper?) from which the Proposition is taken.  Likely the points you have difficulty with are closely related to material presented in the build-up to this statement and proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given spaces $X,Y$ and subspaces $A \subset X, B \subset Y$, we say $f \colon (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ if $f(A) \subseteq B$. Hence the quotient map $q \colon (X,A) \to (X/A, A/A)$. Imagine this as the map which shrinks $A$ to a point.

Edit: As you asked for a specific example, consider $X = S^2$, and $A$ the equator of the sphere. Then the quotient map shrinks the equator to a point, leaving us with the wedge of two spheres. I.e. $q \colon (S^2, S^1) \to (S^2 \vee S^2, pt)$.

For your second question, intuitively imagine our shrinking as mentioned above. Outside $A$, we are just stretching X around to the point, but not sealing it off, so $q \colon X-A \to X/A - A/A$ is a homeomorphism. Similarly, $q \colon V-A \to V/A - A/A$ is a homeomorphism.

Now since $q \colon (X-A, V-A) \to (X/A - A/A, V/A - A/A)$ is a homeomorphism, the induced map is an isomorphism.